# Can a laptop power adapter bought with a UK power cord be used with a US power cord?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, power

I bought a Lenovo laptop here in the UK and am shipping it off to my girlfriend in the US. Can she use a standard US power lead for the lead that goes from the laptop power adapter to the wall outlet or will I have to buy a US power adapter for that laptop model?

Comment: If the adapter is rated 110-120V 60Hz then it can be used in the US.  Most laptop bricks are rated about 100-240 and are fine anywhere in the world.

Comment: For her convenience she should get a HP power cord for the US.  I'm thinking that's a 3-pin cord.

Comment: @DanielRHicks [Lenovo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenovo) bought the ThinkPad business (and several others) from IBM. The HP image was found on the 'net.

Comment: OK, I thought the OP said HP, but I see it's Lenovo. I think those are 3-prong as well. Buy the cord for the specific adapter, as the brick-end connectors vary widely.

Comment: @DanielRHicks It isn't on the T410 I have sitting next to me. But that's irrelevant. A 3 pin plug is just generally better (assuming your outlets are up to modern code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to purchase a universal "220v to 110v plug" (which is a "travel" power adapter), such as this adapter plug;

[image: 3 prong Adapter]

If you see a [UL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwriters_Laboratories) certification, that's a strong indication that it can be used in the US (vertical center, right side of the transformer image at the bottom of this answer).

[image: UL Labs]

Another option is to check the laptop's [transformer](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/P/power_brick.html), it's almost certainly marked. You're looking for the "input" line; for example (in the lower left of the image at the bottom),

```
INPUT: 100-240 V ~ 1.7 A 50-60 Hz
```

[image: Transformer detail]

That means the (HP) transformer (pictured) can handle the AC/DC for both US and Europe, and it would just need a new lead. Note that the US does not use [Ring circuits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_circuit).

Comment: She has a UK -> US travel adapter so that should take care of conversion. Thanks very much Elliot!

Comment: The pictured device is *NOT* a "transformer".  It is an adapter, with no voltage-converting ability.

Comment: @DanielRHicks An "AC/DC" adapter *is* a transformer. The laptop takes DC, the mains is AC. Note that the Input is 1.7A and the output is 3.5A (nominal). Also 100-240V in, 18.5V old.

Comment: The top-pictured device is a simple adapter, not a transformer.  The "brick" can be considered a "transformer", though it's an electronic vs magnetic one.  (A transformer does not convert AC to DC.)

Comment: And the presence/absence of a "ring circuit" is irrelevant, aside from the interference those produce.

Comment: *which is a "travel" power transformer* ??

Comment: @DanielRHicks OP's question was unclear, but in the UK the "lead" incorporates a fuse because they typically use ring circuits in the home. That "travel power transformer" was a mistake. Edited.

Comment: Note that if there is a 3-prong plug on the cord the top-pictured adapter should not be used, but rather a 3-prong version.  Pretty sure HP uses 3-prong plugs.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Edited. I agree. Plugs with ground pins are nice (because electrical shocks aren't very fun).